# How do I parse only the keys that interest me?

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping

I've managed to export some jsons which I now want to export to a csv file. However, with my code in its current state, the final csv has approximately one dict per cell. What I want, however, are the values of each key I'm interested in, per column. Each json has a lot of information that I'm actually not interested in - I only want keys like cadId, cadNomeCompleto, cadProfissao and habDes. Some of these are within other categories in each JSON, like habDes, inside of pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosHabilitacoes, inside of cadHabilitacoes, inside of RegistoBiograficoList.

I've searched FOR some JSON documentation to see whether there is some function that takes as inputs the keys, in the way I need. So far, I haven't been able to parse only the keys I want, and export them such as to create uniform columns with the csv file. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong, and give me an idea on how to do this?

```
import json
import csv
from csv import DictWriter


list_json = ['a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a705932387657456c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932395953556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a705932387657456b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a6231684a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoXI_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876574355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657463971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoX_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876566b6c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566b6c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVIII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876566b6c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566b6c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVIII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876566b6c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932395753556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoVII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876566b6b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62315a4a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoVI_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876566955794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e76566c3971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoV_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a70593238765356596c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62306c575832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoIV_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a705932387653556c4a4a5449775447566e61584e7359585231636d4576556d566e61584e3062304a706232647959575a705932394a53556c66616e4e76626935306548513d&fich=RegistoBiograficoIII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a705932387653556b6c4d6a424d5a5764706332786864485679595339535a57647063335276516d6c765a334a685a6d6c6a62306c4a5832707a6232347564486830&fich=RegistoBiograficoII_json.txt&Inline=true',
             'a7059323876513239756333527064485670626e526c4c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e765132397563313971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoCons_json.txt&Inline=true']


result = []

for i in list_json:
    url = 'http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575{}'.format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = r.json()
    result.append(cont)


with open('bio.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, ('?xml', 'RegistoBiografico'))
    writer.writerows(result)
```

Comment: You can manually specify the elements in your json response, `cont[key1], cont[key2][subkey]`. You'll probably then need to handle `KeyError` exceptions if you can't be sure all of the data is present. If the json hierarchy is complex you could use [jsonpath](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath/) to extract the desired elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've done as you suggested - ```cont['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']```, and now I've arrived at a similar problem: within each JSON subkey of interest, i have 311 dicts from where I want to find the specific keys I mentioned - contingent on ``` KeyError``` exceptions. I want to do this for each JSON. Any advice on how to loop through those 311 dicts in search for the keys' values I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the subkeys to extract your data, e.g.

```
result = []
for child in cont['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']:
    tmp_row = []
    # iterate through keys in which we're interested
    for k in ['cadId', 'cadNomeCompleto', 'cadProfissao']:
        try:
            tmp_row.append(child[k])
        except KeyError:
            print(f"  missing {k} for {child['cadId']}")
            # insert None for missing value so columns still match
            tmp_row.append(None)
    result.append(tmp_row)
```

Running this shows a few entries don't have all the data:

```
  missing cadProfissao for 5950
  missing cadProfissao for 6063
  missing cadProfissao for 6121
  missing cadProfissao for 5534
  missing cadProfissao for 695
  missing cadProfissao for 5952
  missing cadProfissao for 4104
  missing cadProfissao for 4389
  missing cadProfissao for 2445
>>> result[123]
['5854', 'ISABEL CRISTINA RUA PIRES', 'operadora de call cen´ter']
>>>
```

To add the nested key, you could insert `tmp_row.append(child['a']['b]['c'])`, but then you'd also need to duplicate the handling of missing values.

Using the [jsonpointer](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpointer/) module, you can specify a path to the variable you're after:

```
from jsonpointer import resolve_pointer as j_get
result = []
search_dict = {
  'Id': '/cadId',
  'NomeCompleto': '/cadNomeCompleto',
  'Profissao':'/cadProfissao',
  'habDes':'/cadHabilitacoes/pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosHabilitacoes/habDes',
}

for child in cont['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']:
    tmp_row = []
    # iterate through keys in which we're interested
    for k in search_dict.keys():
        tmp_row.append(j_get(child, search_dict[k], None))
    result.append(tmp_row)
```

I've removed the `KeyError` exception handling as I've provided a default value, `None` to the `resolve_pointer` function. Now the result contains:

```
>>> result[123]
['5854', 'ISABEL CRISTINA RUA PIRES', 'operadora de call cen´ter', 'Ciência Política']
```

In case you're interested in which or how many rows are incomplete, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> len([x for x in result if None in x])
165
```

But that'll be easier to look at in your csv output.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you very much :)